# no firebase app ' default ' has been created - call firebase.initializeapp()

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication on my app. Even tough I am calling Firebase.initializeApp in my main, it does not accept it and gives this error. In my pubspec.yaml dependencies, everything is up to date. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Can you help me?

**main.dart**

````
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:widget_catalog/screen/login/login.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Login(),
    );
  }
}  ```



**pubspec.yaml**

dependencies:
  provider: ^5.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  table_calendar: ^3.0.0
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^19.1.63
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
````

Comment: Have you added the google-services.json in your android/app folder (or GoogleServices-info.plist in your ios/Runner folder)?

Comment: You're missing `()` after `await Firebase.initializeApp;`. So: `await Firebase.initializeApp();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumping off of @Frank van Puffelen said.

You're missing `()` `await Firebase.initializeApp`. It needs to be `await Firebase.initializeApp()`. And as long as you have your google services files imported correctly, you should be good!